# Run-time error '1004': Method 'OLEObjects' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel

Friend sent me a spreadsheet that they downloaded and have been using for a while, now anytime they click on a cell they get:
`Run-time error '1004': Method 'OLEObjects' of object'_Worksheet' failed.`

I am getting the same error. I have absolutely zero knowledge of visual basic, so I figured while I try and figure out what is going on in the code I would post my error on here. Any help is appreciated. Thankyou.

> error debugger highlights the line  **`Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("TempCombo")`**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim str As String
    Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    If Target.Column <> 3 Then
        If cboTemp.Visible = True Then
            With cboTemp
                .Visible = False
                .Top = 10
                .Left = 10
                '.ListFillRange = ""
                .LinkedCell = ""
                TempCombo.Value = ""
                TempCombo.Clear
            End With
        End If
    End If

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        With cboTemp
            'show the combobox with the list
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width
            .Height = Target.Height + 5
            '.ListFillRange = ws.Range("pickdata").Address 
            'ws.Range("AB2", ws.Range("AB2").End(xlDown).Address).Address 
            ' ws.Range("AB2").End(xlDown).Address 
            ' ws.Range("AB2", "ab300").Address 
            ' ws.Range(str).Address
            .LinkedCell = Target.Address
            .Visible = True
        End With
        cboTemp.Activate
        TempCombo_Change 'force the combobox to fill
    End If

exitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description
    GoTo exitHandler '   Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End Sub


Private Sub TempCombo_Change()
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
Dim s As String, i As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, j As Long, fullmatch As Boolean
Dim ar() As String
If TempCombo.ListIndex >= 0 Then 'we have a selection

Else
    'TempCombo.DropDown

    If pickdata Is Nothing Then
        SetPickData
    Else
        If LCase(Left(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value, 9)) = "cleanable" And activedbclean = False Then
            SetPickData
        Else
            If LCase(Left(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value, 9)) <> "cleanable"  And activedbclean = True Then
                SetPickData
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set rng = pickdata
    'Set cboTemp = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    s = TempCombo.Value
    TempCombo.Clear
    i = 0
    For Each cell In rng
        ar = Split(s, " ", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
        j = 0
        fullmatch = True
        Do While j <= UBound(ar) And fullmatch = True
            If InStr(1, LCase(cell.Value), LCase(ar(j)), vbTextCompare) <= 0     Then
                fullmatch = False
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        If fullmatch = True Then 'InStr(1, LCase(cell.Value), LCase(s), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'If InStr(1, LCase(cell.Value), LCase(s), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            TempCombo.AddItem cell.Value
            'If s = "" Then
                i = i + 1
            'End If
        End If
        If i > 50 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
    TempCombo.Enabled = False
    TempCombo.Enabled = True
    TempCombo.DropDown
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide the business logic for this code snippet: what exactly you expect it to do (btw, where is the Sub TempCombo_Change)? Thanks and regards,

Comment: Perhaps the active sheet is incorrect? Is there a choice to select a different sheet before setting the macro running?

Comment: I have tried on all of the sheets, and I am just trying to change the data inside the cell currently, other than that. This is a file with a sheet for every room in a house saving prices of stuff in the house quantities and what not. I am unsure of what the macros are doing. I added the sub TempCombo_Change() into the code (its at the bottom i seperated it with 4 new lines). Sorry that i am of little help.

Comment: From what I am told the only thing in the sheet that should be edited is the  individual cell the user clicks on. The second you click on a cell, you get the error.

Comment: Is there a `tempCombo` control in this workbook of yours?

Comment: I am unsure, I found out that the person I was trying to fix this for didnt need any of the background stuff going on, they just wanted the template, so i copy pasted it all into a  new excel sheet and it is working fine. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I put it all in a new excel sheet. Does what the person wanted. Thanks all for the help.